# issue while ordering puppet class execution

Tags: class, puppet

I have this recursive copy action called through

```
class first_class{
    file{'some name':
                    ensure => 'directory',
                    path => '/path/to/here',
                    owner  => 'some_owner',
                    group  => 'some_group',
                    recurse => remote,
                    source => 'puppet:///modules/scripts'
            }
}
class second_class{
file{'tmp':
                ensure => 'present',
                path => '/path/to/here/tmp.sh',
                owner => 'some_owner',
                group => 'some_group',
                mode => '0755',
                notify => Exec['some_process']
                }
}
```

The files are recursively copied but the content is not. So it seems that the file is recreated by the `second_class`, however in my main manifest file I have

```
node default {

Class { 'my_module::first_class':} -> Class { 'my_module::second_class':}
```

Is there a way to tackle it ?

Answer (score 1):

> The files are recursively copied but the content is not. So it seems that the file is recreated by the `second_class`

Actually, no, that's not quite what is happening.  Your `second_class` contains an explicit declaration of `File['tmp']`.  Each resource can be declared only once, and explicit `File` declarations take precedence over implicit ones generated for the contents of recursively-managed directories.  This is a feature.  Thus, the file in question is not being *re*created by the explicit declaration; rather, it is being managed *only* according to that declaration.

Because `File['tmp']` uses `ensure => present`, it accepts any form of file (directory, symlink, regular file, etc.), and if there is no such file at all then it will create an empty ordinary file.  That's what you observe.  It has nothing to do with order of resource application.

> Is there a way to tackle it ?

Yes.  If you want the file to be managed via `File['some name']` then do not declare an explicit resource for it.  If you must declare it explicitly, *e.g.* so as to set its `notify` property, then make that declaration reflect the complete desired target-machine state.

Overall, I suspect you might benefit from some refactoring, as the situation has some code smell.  Be aware also that recursive file management has *always* been ... quirky ... at best.  It has its uses, but often you are better off with something else.

Comment: one thing to add, under the hood, I believe it creates a file resource for everything that it copies, so fi you need to refer to something, you may be able to do something like `File['/path/to/here/tmp.sh'] -> exec{'cmd that requires file': ...}`, even if you omit the explicit file resource that was mentioned above

Comment: Yes, @Cinderhaze, it does create a `File` resource for each otherwise-unmanaged file managed as part of the recursion, but that doesn't happen until the catalog is applied.  As such, you cannot *refer* to such `File` resources in your manifests -- they are unknown to the catalog builder, and not explicitly represented in the generated catalog.